# Array Manipulation in Liquid shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, liquid

I am trying to work out a conditional iteration in Liquid. This is what i have

```
 {% capture title_tag %}
    {% for teacher in course.teachers %}
      {% if course.teachers.size == 1 %}
        {{course.title}} with {{ teacher.name | escape }}
      {% elsif course.teachers.size > 1 %}
        {{ course.title }} with {{ teacher.name }} 
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
 {% endcapture %}
```

As expected, the first 'if' condition works well and i get an output like this

> "Intro to Maths with Isaac Newton".

My problem is with the `elsif`, thus when the teacher size is greater than 1. I get this

> "Intro to Maths with Isaac Newton Intro to Maths with Elon Musk".

What I actually want is

> "Intro to Maths with Isaac Newton and Elon Musk"

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you want the `course.title` to be printed *not inside a loop*.

```
{% capture title_tag %}
  {{ course.title }} with  ⇐ !!!! HERE
  {% for teacher in course.teachers %}
    {% if course.teachers.size == 1 %}
      {{ teacher.name | escape }}
    {% elsif course.teachers.size > 1 %}
      {{ teacher.name }} 
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

joining the names with `and` is more tricky and requires additional coding. Maybe you should just use `String#join`:

```
{% capture title_tag %}
  {{ course.title }} with
  {{ course.teachers.map { |t| t.name }.join(', ') }}
{% endcapture %}
```

Comment: Your 2nd short answer is correct. In first answer `{{ course.title }} with  ⇐ !!!! HERE` will print twice if `course.teachers==2`

Comment: @Salil indeed, thanks, I originally put in one line below it should have been. Thx.

Comment: the first code works but i get an error with the second one, "Liquid syntax error (line 4): Unexpected character & in "{{ course.teachers.map(&:name).join(', ') }}".

Comment: Goddamn liquid :) Fixed the answer.

Comment: i get this error with the new answer "Liquid syntax error (line 4): Variable '{{ course.teachers.map { |t| t.name }' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/".   Have no idea why i need a regex

Comment: Please, forget about the latter and use the former. **If any visitor knows how to fix the latter, please apply a direct edit to this answer, thanks!**

Comment: sure, thanks for your time and effort. I would stick with the first and check back if there is an edit to the second